# How to get the values selected in a group of select boxes that are generated dynamically in Angular 8?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I generate a grid list whose tiles contain individual select boxes. I will not know how many of these select boxes will be available until the time of rendering.

I am able to generate this view through the following code.

```
<mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let tile of segmentNameArr"  class="grid-bg-blue">
  <div class="select-column">
    <div style="color:#fff">{{tile.segmentName}}</div>
    <mat-select style="background-color: white;">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let dataTypes of tile.arrList" [value]="dataTypes.valueName">
            {{dataTypes.valueName}}
          </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </div>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

[image]

My issue is, when all the values are selected, how do I collect all the values chosen in all the select boxes at the time of button click (Add)?

Comment: I nerver use the mat components but with classical component you have ton bind the select component with a ngModel to retrieve his data. Your tile can look like `{segmentName:"item name",value:""}` and then bind your select `<select [(ngModel)]="tile.value">...</select>` according to your tile object will be }`{segmentName:"item nam",value"selected value"}`. By the way you may want to look about reactive forms [doco](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Comment: Hey @Nico , you certainly pushed me in the right direction. Thanks for the input.